# Copy files to BlackBerry programmatically

Tags: java, blackberry, file, copy

I'm wondering if there's any command line tool for copying files (images, music) to BlackBerry device.
For installing software, there's a JavaLoader commandline tool, but it doesn't seem to support simple file copy. Any other alternatives? Perhaps it's accessible directly via file system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I plug my blackberry into my computer it offers to enable mass storage.   Enabling this makes the BlackBerry filesystem available to the computer.